How do I change Spring app using Postgres to use ElasticSearch as datastore?
I have a Spring application using Postgres as the datastore. I would like to use ElasticSearch instead. If someone has experience making a similar change, I would appreciate hearing the details. Can anyone describe the code changes that may be necessary. I assume it's not as simple as adding the "spring-data-elasticsearch" library and extending ElasticsearchRepository to all of my repository classes. If there is an example out there, can someone please post here? Thanks.
So far I have only searched the topic without getting any helpful results.

That should be more or less it apart from the data migration because the data doesn't auto magically appear in ElasticSearch, and are you sure you want to move all your data to ElasticSearch?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
